# CasperJS dont load page resources

Tags: casperjs

How can I tell casper not to load images,css ,js videos etc . So I am interested only in DOM elements .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have a look at the [CasperJS API](http://casperjs.org/api.html).

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,        // do not load images
        loadPlugins: false         // do not load NPAPI plugins (Flash, Silverlight, ...)
    }
});
```